# Magento inline translation disabled on one specific page

Tags: magento, translation

I have a mystery question: in my magento shop there is a specific page (part of /customer/account but from an extension) where inline translation is not working at all.

To be more specific: If inline translation is enabled for the entire shop, then it does usually work fine. Menus, Sub-Menus, Titles, everything can be translated.
But as soon I navigate to said page, I can't translate anything on the whole site. Not even the Menus and Sub-Menus, that do not even belong to the requested page.
As soon as I navigate to another page, translation works fine again.

I'm really lost and I hope that you guys can point me to places where this might be configurated?

for full disclousure: the extension mentioned is Webkul_Marketplacepartner and the page mentioned is marketplacepartner/partnerproducts/mydashboard/

the source code of the phtml looks like this:

```
<?php 
$customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$isPartner= Mage::getModel('marketplaceprofile/marketplaceprofile')->isPartner($customerid);
$partner=Mage::getModel('marketplaceprofile/marketplaceprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($customerid);
if($isPartner==1){?>
<link href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/css/global.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/css/jquery.jqplot.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/css/webkul-image-slider.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/css/shCoreDefault.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/css/shThemejqPlot.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jquery.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/shCore.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/shBrushJScript.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/shBrushXml.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('Customerpartner/js/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
div.example-plot { height: 400px;width: 650px;}
</style>
<?php   

        $mysqlprefix = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');


    $k="";

    $i=0;
    $Optioncreated=0;

    // prefix checking and execute code

    $j=0;$op=0;
    $weeklytotal=0;
    $todaytotal=0.0;
    $yeartotal=0.0;

    $sk=array();
    $allskulist=array();
    $allmageprolist=array();
    $$allorderids=array();
    $s1=0;
    $s2=0;
    $s5=0;

    $today=date("Y-m-d");

    $sqlQuery = "select * from ".$mysqlprefix."marketplacepartner_entity_saleslist where mageproownerid =".$customerid." order by autoid desc";
    $querydata=$write->query($sqlQuery);
    $grandTotal = array();
    $dataArr= array();
    $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();


    foreach($write->fetchAll($sqlQuery) as $row){ 

        $l=explode('-',$row['cleared_at']);
        $day=substr($row['cleared_at'],0,10);
        $row['actualparterprocost'] = round(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($row['actualparterprocost'], $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode),2); 

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($row['magerealorderid']);


        if($order->getStatus()!='pending'){
            if($day==$today){
            $todaytotal+=$row['actualparterprocost'];
            }
            $week_number = date('W');
            $year = date('Y');

            for($days=1; $days<=7; $days++)
            {
                $m=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$days));

                if($day==trim($m))
                {   
                    $row['magerealorderid'].$weeklytotal=$row['actualparterprocost']+$weeklytotal;
                }
            }
            $grandTotal[$l[1]]=$row['actualparterprocost']+$grandTotal[$l[1]];

            $dataArr[]= $row;
        }

    }
?>
<div class="prdouctbackground">
    <div class="maindash">
        <h4 class="textcolor"><span><?php echo $this->__('My Vendor Dashboard') ?></span></h4>
        <div class="salesmonth">
             <div class="todaydash"><?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();  if($todaytotal<=0) {echo 0;} else {echo $todaytotal;}?>&nbsp;<span class="textcolordash">&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Today') ?></span>
             </div>
             <div class="weekdash"><?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); if($weeklytotal<=0){ echo 0;} else {echo $weeklytotal;}?>&nbsp;<span class="textcolordash">&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Week') ?></span>
             </div>
             <div class="monthdash"><?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); 
                        $d=date('m');
                        echo $grandTotal[$d];
                ?>
                &nbsp;
                <span class="textcolordash"><?php echo $this->__('Month') ?></span>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="salesemail"></div>
        <div class="orderdproduct">
            <table class="tablepostioneditdash">
                <thead><tr>
                    <th class="headingbg"><span><?php echo $this->__('Latest Order') ; ?> </span></th>
                </tr></thead>
                <tbody id="tbodyingeditdash">
                <?php
                    $m=0;

                    foreach($dataArr as $key=>$val){

                        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($val['magerealorderid']);


                        if($order->getStatus()!= 'pending'){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="tdpadfirsteditheadingdash">

                                    <label for="name" class="rightgapeditheadedit">
                                    <?php if($order->getStatus()=='pending') {?>
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:orange"><?php echo $this->__(strtoupper($order->getStatus())); ?> </div>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    <?php if($order->getStatus()=='canceled') {?>
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:red"><?php echo $this->__(strtoupper($order->getStatus())); ?> </div>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    <?php if($order->getStatus()=='complete') {?>
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:green"><?php echo $this->__(strtoupper($order->getStatus())); ?> </div>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    <?php if($order->getStatus()=='delivered') {?>
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:green"><?php echo $this->__(strtoupper($order->getStatus())); ?> </div>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    <?php if($order->getStatus()=='processing') {?>
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:blue"><?php echo $this->__(strtoupper($order->getStatus())); ?> </div>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    <p style="margin: 0 0 10px 6px;"><?php echo "<br>".$val['cleared_at']; ?></p> </label> 
                                </th>
                                <th class="tdpadfirsteditheadingdash">
                                    <label for="name" class="rightgapeditheadedit">
                                        <div class="textcolordashdiv"><?php echo $this->__('Order'); ?> #<?php echo $val['magerealorderid']; ?></div>
                                        <?php $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
                                         if ( $shipping_address != null) {
                                        ?>

                                        <div class="dd">
                                            <?php  echo "By: " . $shipping_address->getCustomerId(); ?>
                                            <br>

                                        <?php
                                            $orddataing="SELECT * FROM ".$mysqlprefix."sales_flat_order_item where order_id='".$val['mageorderid']."' ORDER BY order_id DESC";
                                            //$sqlProductQuery = "select * from ".$mysqlprefix."marketplacepartner_entity_saleslist where mageproownerid =".$customerid." AND magerealorderid='".$val['magerealorderid']."'";
                                            $ordconnectioning = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                                            //$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderidenitity[$x]);
                                            //$priceTwo = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($aa, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode); 


                                            $shipammount=(int)$order->getShippingAmount();
                                            $count=0;
                                            $product;
                                            foreach($ordconnectioning->fetchAll($orddataing) as $ordername){
                                                $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ordername['product_id']);
                                                if($ordername['product_id'] == $val['mageproid']){
                                                      if($count==0){
                                                        echo "<p style='color:silver;float:left;'>" . (int)$ordername['qty_ordered']."&nbsp;x&nbsp;".$ordername['name']." (" . $product->getSku() .")</p>"; $proid[$m]=$ordername['product_id'];
                                                    }else{
                                                        echo "<p style='color:silver;float:left;'>,&nbsp;". (int)$ordername['qty_ordered']."&nbsp;x&nbsp;".$ordername['name']." (" . $product->getSku() .")</p>"; $proid[$m]=$ordername['product_id'];
                                                    }
                                                    $count++;
                                                    $m++;
                                                }
                                            }?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </label> 
                                </th>
                                <th class="tdpadfirsteditheadingdash">
                                    <?php
                                    /* (2014-01-07 AM) disabled till further notice */
                                    ?>
                                    <label for="name" class="rightgapeditheadprice"><?php echo $this->__('Net margin') . ': '; echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); echo "&nbsp;".$val['actualparterprocost']?> </label>
                                    <?php
                                    /**/
                                    ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                <?php if($order->getStatus()=='processing') {?> <label for="name" class="rightgapeditheadedit">
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:blue"><?php echo $this->__('Ready To Shipped'); ?></div>
                                        <p style='color:silver;text-align:center;'><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/products/sendemailtoadmin') ?>?id=<?php echo $val['mageorderid'];?>"><?php echo $this->__('Click To Ship Item'); ?></a></p>
                                        <p style='color:silver;text-align:center;'><?php 
                                         if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
                                            $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
                                            $invoice->register();
                                            //$invoice->setEmailSent(true);
                                            $invoice->save();
                                            //$invoice->sendEmail();
                                          $invoiceID = $invoice->getId(); ?>
                                             <?php
                                             /*
                                             (2014-01-07 AM) disable till further notice
                                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/order/printInvoice/invoice_id/'.$invoiceID.'/') ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->__('Print Invoice'); ?></a>
                                             */
                                             ?>
                                        <?php } ?></p>
                                        </label> 
                                    <?php }?>
                                <?php       $updatedDate = $order->getUpdatedAt();
                                            $terminationDays  = $partner['terminationperiod'];
                                            $TotalTime = strtotime($updatedDate) +  $terminationDays * 86400;
                                            $currentTime = time();
                                             ?> 
                                <?php if($order->getStatus()=='delivered') {?>
                                <label for="name" class="rightgapeditheadedit">
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:green"><?php echo $this->__('Item Delivered'); ?></div></label> 
                                        <p style='color:silver;text-align:center;'><?php
                                         if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
                                            $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
                                            $invoice->register();
                                            //$invoice->setEmailSent(true);
                                            $invoice->save();
                                            //$invoice->sendEmail();
                                          $invoiceID = $invoice->getId(); ?>
                                             <?php
                                             /*
                                             (2014-01-07 AM) disable till further notice
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/order/invoice/order_id/'.$orderidenitity[$x].'/') ?>" target="_blank">Print Invoice</a>
                                             */
                                             ?>
                                        <?php 

                                            if($currentTime <= $TotalTime){
                                        ?> 
                                            <p style='color:silver;text-align:center;'><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/products/sendreceiveconfirmation') ?>?vid=<?php echo $customerid;?>&id=<?php echo $val['mageorderid']; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Click After Item Received'); ?></a></p>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            </p>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php if($order->getStatus()=='complete') {?>
                                <label for="name" class="rightgapeditheadedit">
                                        <div class="status" style="background-color:green"><?php echo $this->__('Item Delivered'); ?></div></label> 
                                        <p style='color:silver;text-align:center;'><?php 
                                         if ($order->hasInvoices()) { 
                                            $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
                                            $invoice->register();
                                            //$invoice->setEmailSent(true);
                                            $invoice->save();
                                            //$invoice->sendEmail();
                                            $invoiceID = $invoice->getId();
                                        ?>
                                             <?php
                                             /*
                                             (2014-01-07 AM) disable till further notice
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/order/invoice/order_id/'.$val['mageorderid'].'/') ?>" target="_blank">Print Invoice</a>
                                             */
                                             ?>
                                        <?php if($currentTime <= $TotalTime){
                                        ?> 
                                            <p style='color:silver;text-align:center;'><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/products/sendreceiveconfirmation') ?>?vid=<?php echo $customerid;?>&id=<?php echo $val['mageorderid']; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Click After Item Received'); ?></a></p>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                            <?php } ?></p>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <?php //} ?>

                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        <?php

                        }else { }
                    }
                ?>  
                </tbody>                
            </table>                
        </div>
        <div class="review">
            <h4 colspan="2" class="headingbg"><?php echo $this->__('Latest Comments & Reviews'); ?></h4>
            <table class="reviewtable">     
            <?php   
                $c=0;$cc=0;$r=0;
                // prefix checking and execute code
                $productget="select entity_pk_value from ".$mysqlprefix."review ORDER BY created_at DESC";
                $ownerread = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                $q5=0;
                foreach($ownerread->fetchAll($productget) as $value){
                    $storepro[$q5]=$value['entity_pk_value'];
                    $q5++;
                }
                $listingpro = array_unique($storepro);
                foreach($listingpro as $q2){    
                    $allpro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($q2);
                    $owner=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEntityid();
                    $ownerconnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                    // prefix checking and execute code
                    $cusresult=$ownerconnection->query("SELECT * FROM ".$mysqlprefix."marketplacepartner_entity_data where userid='".Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEntityid()."' and sku='".$allpro['sku']."'");
                    $ownerkey=$cusresult->fetch();
                    if($allpro['sku']==$ownerkey['sku']){  
                        $ownerread = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                        // mysql prefix checking and execute code
                        $ownerreadresulting=$ownerread->query("select * from ".$mysqlprefix."review where entity_pk_value ='".$allpro['entity_id']."' ORDER BY created_at DESC");
                        $ownerget=$ownerreadresulting->fetch(); 
                        // prefix checking and execute code
                        $ownerreviewresulting=$ownerread->query("select * from  ".$mysqlprefix."review_detail  where review_id ='".$ownerget['review_id']."' ORDER BY review_id  DESC");
                        $ownerreviewget=$ownerreviewresulting->fetch();
                        // here i code for mysql prefix checking and execute code
                        $ratdatasql="select rating_summary from ".$mysqlprefix."review_entity_summary where entity_pk_value='".$allpro['entity_id']."' ORDER BY primary_id DESC";
                        $ownerrateresult=$ownerread->query($ratdatasql);
                        $ownerrateresulting=$ownerrateresult->fetch();
                        if((gettype($ownerreviewget)=='array')&& (gettype($ownerrateresulting)=='array')){ 
                            if(($c==0)||($c==1)){?>
                                <tr  class="ex2">
                                    <th class="reviewtablethleft">
                                    <?php
                                        $detail=$ownerreviewget['title'];
                                        $nickname=$ownerreviewget['nickname'];
                                        $status_id=$ownerget['status_id'];
                                        $created_at=$ownerget['created_at'];
                                        $rating_summary=$ownerrateresulting['rating_summary'];
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="ratingslider-box"><div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo ceil($rating_summary);?>%;"></div></div>
                                    <?php $productcity=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($allpro['entity_id']); ?>
                                        <p class="rightgapeditheadedit" style="margin: 5px 0 10px 6px;float: left;"><?php echo $this->__('Product') ?> : </p>
                                        <p class="textcolorproalter"><?php echo $productcity['name']; ?></p>
                                        <p class="rightgapeditheadedit" style="margin: 0 0 10px 6px;float: left;"><?php echo $this->__('Comment By') ?>: </p>
                                        <p class="textcolorproalter"><?php echo $nickname; ?></p>
                                        <p class="rightgapeditheadedit" style="margin: 0 0 10px 6px;float: left;">  </p>
                                        <p class="textcolorproalter1"><?php echo $detail; ?></p>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="reviewtablethright">
                                        <br><br>
                                        <?php if($status_id==1){?>
                                                <p class="statusapp"><?php echo $this->__('Approved'); ?></p>
                                        <?php } else{ ?>
                                                <p class="statussunapp"><?php echo $this->__('Unapproved'); ?></p>
                                        <?php }?>
                                        <br>
                                            <p class="rightgapeditheadedit" style="margin:0 0 10px 37%;float: left;"><?php echo $this->__('Review On') ?> : </p>
                                            <p class="textcolorpro"> <?php echo trim($created_at); ?></p>
                                            <?php $c++;?>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                        <?php }
                        }
                        $r++;
                    }
                }?> 
            </table>    
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php
    /*(2014-01-07 AM) disabled till further notice
        <div class="example-plot" id="chart2"></div>
    */
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="button-set buttonarea">
    <p class="headingbackindex">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript: window.history.back();" class="left">&laquo; <?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
    <?php
    /*(2014-01-07 AM) disabled till further notice

<script class="code" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
     var line2 = [['1/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($aa<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $aa; }?>], ['2/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($bb<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $bb; }?>], ['3/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>',<?php  if($cc<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $cc; }?>], ['4/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>',<?php  if($dd<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $dd; }?>], ['5/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>',<?php  if($ee<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ee; }?>], ['6/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($ff<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ff; }?>], ['7/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($gg<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $gg; }?>], ['8/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($hh<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $hh; }?>], ['9/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($ii<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ii; }?>], ['10/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($jj<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $jj; }?>], ['11/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($kk<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $kk; }?>], ['12/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($ll<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ll; }?>]];

    var plot2 = jQuery.jqplot('chart2', [line2], {
      axes: {
        xaxis: {
          renderer: jQuery.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          label: '<?php echo $this->__("Month"); ?>',
          labelRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
          tickRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
          tickOptions: {angle: 30}
        },
        yaxis: {
          label: '<?php echo $this->__("Money") ?>',
          labelRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
    */
    ?>

<?php }else{
    echo "<h2 style='color:#ff0000;font-weight:600'>".$this->__('FOR BECOME SELLER CONTACT TO ADMIN..')."</h2>";
}?>
```

please note that this code is not mine. I just have to deal with it.. -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered by the support team of the modules developers. the reason for the not working inline translation was an error in a java script.

the fix looks like this:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();
(function($wk_jq){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var line2 = [['1/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($aa<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $aa; }?>], ['2/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($bb<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $bb; }?>], ['3/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>',<?php  if($cc<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $cc; }?>], ['4/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>',<?php  if($dd<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $dd; }?>], ['5/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>',<?php  if($ee<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ee; }?>], ['6/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($ff<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ff; }?>], ['7/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($gg<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $gg; }?>], ['8/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($hh<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $hh; }?>], ['9/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($ii<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ii; }?>], ['10/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($jj<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $jj; }?>], ['11/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($kk<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $kk; }?>], ['12/1/<?php echo date('Y');?>', <?php  if($ll<=0){ echo 0; } else { echo $ll; }?>]];

    var plot2 = jQuery.jqplot('chart2', [line2], {
      axes: {
        xaxis: {
          renderer: jQuery.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          label: '<?php echo $this->__("Month"); ?>',
          labelRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
          tickRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
          tickOptions: {angle: 30}
        },
        yaxis: {
          label: '<?php echo $this->__("Money") ?>',
          labelRenderer: jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        }
      }
    });
});
})($wk_jq);

</script>
```